# Figure to image as a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a numpy array image from a Matplotlib figure and I'm currently doing it by saving to a file, then reading the file back in, but I feel like there has to be a better way.  Here's what I'm doing now:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.gca()

ax.text(0.0,0.0,"Test", fontsize=45)
ax.axis('off')

canvas.print_figure("output.png")
image = plt.imread("output.png")
```

I tried this:

```
image = np.fromstring( canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8' )
```

from an example I found but it gives me an error saying that 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In order to get the figure contents as RGB pixel values, the `matplotlib.backend_bases.Renderer` needs to first draw the contents of the canvas.

You can do this by manually calling `canvas.draw()`:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure()
canvas = fig.canvas
ax = fig.gca()

ax.text(0.0,0.0,"Test", fontsize=45)
ax.axis('off')

canvas.draw()  # Draw the canvas, cache the renderer

image_flat = np.frombuffer(canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')  # (H * W * 3,)
# NOTE: reversed converts (W, H) from get_width_height to (H, W)
image = image_flat.reshape(*reversed(canvas.get_width_height()), 3)  # (H, W, 3)
```

[See here](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html) for more info on the Matplotlib API.

Comment: I get the img as 1d array, you can fix that using:

`width, height = fig.get_size_inches() * fig.get_dpi()` and
`img = np.fromstring(canvas.to_string_rgb(), dtype='uint8').reshape(height, width, 3)
`

Comment: I sometimes get an error where height and width are floats, converting them to integers is an easy fix though.

Comment: I edited the answer to include @MaxNoe 's suggestion.

Comment: Do we really have to call `canvas.draw()` to make this work?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari One way or another the contents of the canvas need to have been rendered at least once before you can fetch the pixel values. Rendering can happen as a side-effect of other operations, e.g. if the canvas belongs to a pyplot figure and you call `plt.show()` to display it then the canvas will be rendered. However in the example above, if you get rid of the call to `canvas.draw` you'll get `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'` (try it).

Comment: NOTE  `tostring_rgb` is deprecated.  A much better solution is here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040123/1812732

Answer (score 30):

For people who are searching an answer for this question, this is the code gathered from previous answers. Keep in mind that the method `np.fromstring` is deprecated and `np.frombuffer` is used instead.

```
#Image from plot
ax.axis('off')
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

# To remove the huge white borders
ax.margins(0)

fig.canvas.draw()
image_from_plot = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
image_from_plot = image_from_plot.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
```

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the changes that improves the answer significantly

Comment: @rayreng Is it possible to get a grayscale output? I don't see a method similar to `tostring_rgb` on the canvas

Comment: thanks for compiling answers! I should also add that the order of commands (especially `fig.canvas.draw()`) is very important. My code didn't work out initially due to wrong ordering.

Answer (score 16):

from the docs:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/canvasagg.html#sphx-glr-gallery-user-interfaces-canvasagg-py

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
# A canvas must be manually attached to the figure (pyplot would automatically
# do it).  This is done by instantiating the canvas with the figure as
# argument.
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

# your plotting here

canvas.draw()
s, (width, height) = canvas.print_to_buffer()

# Option 2a: Convert to a NumPy array.
X = np.fromstring(s, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
```

Answer (score 11):

I think there is some update, which is easier.

```
canvas.draw()
buf = canvas.buffer_rgba()
X = np.asarray(buf)
```

Updated version from the docs:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

# make a Figure and attach it to a canvas.
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

# Do some plotting here
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

# Retrieve a view on the renderer buffer
canvas.draw()
buf = canvas.buffer_rgba()
# convert to a NumPy array
X = np.asarray(buf)
```

Comment: This is the version that worked for me. `np.fromstring` is deprecated, and without specifying `FigureCanvasAgg` some platforms give an error, on macOS for example`FigureCanvasMac` has no `renderer` attribute. I find incredible how complicated such an operation is :(

Comment: To render an image of a specific size (for example, a 1024 by 512 image), do `fig = Figure(figsize=(1024, 512), dpi=1)` when constructing figure.

Comment: @lingjiankong : no, because you'll get `RuntimeError: In set_size: Could not set the fontsize (error code 0x97)` because the `dpi` is set too low to render fonts. prefer a `fig = Figure(figsize=(10.24, 5.12), dpi=100.0)` instead, it won't change the final picture size, but it pleases `matplotlib` better this way.

Answer (score 5):

To fix the large margins Jorge references, add `ax.margins(0)`. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins) for details.

Comment: also you can use `plt.tight_layout(pad=-10)` which allows negative numbers for extreme cropping.  I have no idea what are the units of `pad` are, perhaps tenths of an inch?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a byte stream as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create sample plot
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
y = x**2 
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

# Save figure in PNG format to byte stream
from io import BytesIO
b = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(b, format='png')

# Read back from byte stream
b.seek(0)
img = plt.imread(b)

# Dispose of the stream to save memory
b.close()
del b
```