# Output Matplotlib plot as grayscale array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to output a plot generated by Matplotlib as a grayscale np array with one channel. There are multiple answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355930/matplotlib-figure-to-image-as-a-numpy-array) that generates output as RGB, but I can't find a method similar to `tostring_rgb` to call on the canvas and get it as a grayscale single-channel array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`buffer_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.buffer_rgba) to get the underlying buffer and then convert it to grayscale with your favorite formula, e.g. [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use('agg')
plt.bar([0,1,2], [1,2,3], color=list('cmy'))
canvas = plt.gcf().canvas
canvas.draw()

img = np.array(canvas.buffer_rgba())
img = np.rint(img[...,:3] @ [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]).astype(np.uint8)
```

Result of `mpl.use('qt5agg')`, `plt.imshow(img,'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)`:
[image]