# how to solve scatter is not transparent even I set alpha as low as 0.1

Tags: python, matplotlib, arcgis, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot transparent scatters on a map creating by `matplotlib.basemap` with an `arcgis` image background. I have already set alpha as low as `0.1`, but scatters are still not that transparent. In fact, the scatters do not have any changes when I change alpha. But the color-bar looks normal (see below image), that is the color I want for my scatters. What should I do?

[image]

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
m.shadedrelief()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawrivers()
m.arcgisimage(service = 'Ocean_Basemap')

t1 = t_AS.t
lat = t_AS.latitude
lon = t_AS.longitude
x,y=m(lon,lat)
m.scatter(lon,lat,s=500, c=t1,cmap=plt.cm.jet,alpha=0.1,vmin=195,vmax=360)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('simul1.png')
```

Comment: how dou you generate m?

Comment: Displays the full image instead of link + code formatting

Comment: The scatter dots *are* transparent, but you have many duplicate points, so if you create 100 dots  with alpha 0.1 on top of each other, the overall alpha will be very close to 1.

Comment: You can try limiting your data to only a few (say 10) data points and see if it is really due to a lot of points on top of each other or if it is a different problem.

Comment: If your case is same as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest described, this question could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108372/how-to-make-matplotlib-scatterplots-transparent-as-a-group